# Silverlight: Event Handler Issue

Tags: silverlight, event-handling

So I have a Grid on a page that has a few UserControls on it. Each UserControl has a MouseLeftButtonDown event registered, as does the Grid. Before i added the event to the grid, the events on the user controls worked fine. But now that i have the event on the Grid, only the grid event fires regardless of where i click. None of the UseControls are capturing the event.

What do i need to do to allow the MouseLeftButtonDown events on the UserControls to fire while still having the MouseLeftButtonDown event on the Grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is very unusual.

What would often happen in this case it that **both** events fire.  Since `MouseLeftButtonDown` is a bubbling event when you click on a UserControl it fires its `MouseLeftButtonDown`, if the handler attached to it doesn't set the `Handled` property of the `MouseButtonEventArgs` parameter to True then the event will bubble up to the parent and so on.  If the parent controls also have code attached to their `MouseLeftButtonDown` events that code will also run.

Are sure that in fact the UserControl events don't fire or is that you happen to observe that the Grid event was always firing.  If you are absolutely certain that attaching a event handler to the Grid actually prevents the UserControl events from firing can you edit your question with a small Repro, its very hard to see how this could be the case.

Comment: as it turns out, the event was firing, but a method call in the grid event was doing something that cancelled out the effects of the usercontrol events so it appeared that it wasn't being called. added a simple check to see if the OriginalSource property of the mouse event args is a Grid, and if so, it performed the action that was necessary.